# alignment in standards mode

Tags: gwt, uibinder

according to https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#Standards I 'm not suppose to use DockPanel, VerticalPanel, HorizontalPanel. But Those are the only panels that support hasverticalalignment and hashorizontalalignment. How am I suppose to align the widgets if I want to conform to the standards mode? Or should I keep the project in its current form using VericalPanel and  HorizontalPanel, and ignore the warning eclipse gives me:

> [INFO] [project] - GWT no longer supports Quirks Mode
>   (document.compatMode=' BackCompat').
> Make sure your application's
>   host HTML page has a Standards Mode (document.compatMode='
>   CSS1Compat') doctype,
> e.g. by using <!doctype html> at the
>   start of your application's HTML page.
> To continue using this
>   unsupported rendering mode and risk layout problems, suppress this
>   message by adding
> the following line to your*.gwt.xml module
>   file:
>   <extend-configuration-property
>   name="document.compatMode" value="BackCompat"/>

P.S.: I work in uibinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tables for layouts is considered a bad practice by most UI experts. These layouts are rigid - they don't adjust well with the size of their contents.

You can build any layout you want without using these panels. Horizontal alignment is the easiest one: you simply add a CSS rule "text-align: center" (left, right) to the parent widget. For more interesting effects you can use "float: left" or "float: right". In some rare cases you may event want to use absolute positioning ("position: absolute", "left: 20px"; "top: 20px").

Vertical alignment is a little trickier, but generally you want your content to flow from top to the bottom. You can manage vertical positioning by using top and bottom margins or setting the line heights.

You can find many great resources on building fluid layouts on the Internet. Most suggested html and CSS solutions can be used with GWT, and Ui:Binder is a very convenien way to do so. You can also search StackOverflow for layout solutions to any problem you face.